# accounts and its contacts in different column by using wrapper class

Tags: force.com

how to display account in one column and its contacts in next column?
My code is below :

```
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accnt}" var="a">
     <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
   <apex:repeat value="{!a.contacts}" var="con">
 <apex:column value="{!con.fax}"/>

 </apex:repeat>
  <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
  <apex:repeat value="{!a.opportunities}" var="oppor">
 <apex:column value="{!oppor.type}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
  </apex:pageblocktable>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific, what error are you getting? What's not working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Pageblocktable just lets you enter columns not rows. You should use HTML table with repeat for this.
hope it helps  @AtulRajguru9

Comment: i did'nt get any error but I didn't get expected output.